# Microsoft Remote Desktop to an 8.1 machine

Tags: remote-desktop

Every time I remote into my windows machine it starts what appears to be a new session, rather then picking up where I left off. All of my windows are closed and all precesses that I had started are gone.

When I am finished with a session I generally just close the Remote Desktop application.

Comment: We'll need more info.  Are you trying to resume a previous RDP session, or RDP in and take over your console session?  If you're trying to resume an existing RDP session, how did you exit the previous session? Is this your home computer you're RDPing into, or a work computer?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same credentials from the supposedly previous session you had?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Microsoft's Remote Desktop client, there 'used to be' an option where you could pick to connect to the main console.  <>.  Also if you launch Remote Desktop from the command line with the admin option, this might work.
  ( c:\windows\system32\MSTsc /v:compname /admin )
I am not having those kinds of connection problems, but I am connecting Win8 to Win8. 
-rwg

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the environment was Microsoft Remote Desktop on a Mac connecting to an offsite Windows 8 machine. The solution was to edit the desktop profile from within the MRD on my mac. Under the session tab the option to "Connect to admin session" was not selected.

Thanks to all who responded.